# Getting data from database using SQL but hide my placeholder in textbox in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-core-mvc

I get data from a database using a SQL query in which I search for data and display that data. But in the textbox it already have a value 0 that hides my placeholder. Kindly tell me any other solution.

View:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="price" asp-for="Input.price" 
       style="height: 50px; border-color: black; border-style:solid; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 3px; border-radius: 5px;" />
```

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Rent(inputModel input, int PageNumber = 1)
{
    var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();
    var datas = rdb.GetDataHouse();

    ViewBag.Data = datas.ToList().Take(7);
    ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count() / 6.0);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.areaunit))
    {
        data = data.Where(x => x.areaUnit == input.areaunit & x.area == input.area & x.price <= input.price).ToList();
    }

    data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * 6).Take(6).ToList();

    var viewModel = new RentModel
            {
                Data = data,
                //SearchList =   List<string>(),
                Input = new inputModel(),
            };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Input model:

```
public class inputModel
{
    public string? areaunit { get; set; }
    public int area { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

Rent model:

```
public class RentModel
{
    public List<eHouse.Models.RentModel>? Data { get; set; }
    public List<string>? SearchList { get; set;}
    public inputModel? Input { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the property nullable by changing the `price` declaration to:

```cs
public int? price { get; set; }
```

When the `price` property is declared as `int` it has `0` value by default. Therefore, the `placefolder` doesn't applied.